# What is it called if a thing have different descriptions of the same phenomena?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, definition

Does anyone know what it is called when a thing have different descriptions of the same phenomena?

Some would say it would be called "paradoxical", but that would be if a thing had opposite descriptions of the same phenomena.

In this case it is not opposite, but just different or semi-opposite but not completely opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word "conflicting". E.g.

> "There are two conflicting descriptions of this phenomenon."

It means the descriptions differ in a significant way. They can't both be 100% true because they conflict, but they aren't necessarily complete opposites either.